# How to editColumn of datatable by using <font-color=change>

Tags: laravel

I cannot find the way to create font color in edit column like below.

this is example what i want to do

```
public function list(Request $request){
    $items = Item::get();

    $datatables = DataTables::of($items)
    ->editColumn('stock_qty', function($item){
      if($item->stock_qty <= $item->low_stock_threshold){
        return 'red font';
      } else {
        return 'black font';
      }
    })
    ->rawColumns(['stock_qty']);

    return $datatables->make(true);
  }
```

I try to change some code like this in return but give me empty value.

i make if else to compare the value , if stock_qty low show red font.

```
->editColumn('stock_qty', function($item){
     ** if($item->stock_qty <= $item->low_stock_threshold){
        return '<font color="red> '+ $item->stock_qty +'</font>;
      } else {
        return $stock_qty;
      }
    })**
```

1. the font color change red when low stock else show black.
2. Please help me and thank.

Comment: what you have getting now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concatenation operator in PHP is `.` not `+` like in javascript.

So it should be `return '<font color="red> '. $item->stock_qty .'</font>';`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you missed the double quotes after `red` :)

```
->editColumn('stock_qty', function($item){
 ** if($item->stock_qty <= $item->low_stock_threshold){
    return '<font color="red"> '+ $item->stock_qty +'</font>;
  } else {
    return $stock_qty;
  }
})**
```